# How is this answer not a violation of the "back it up" policy?

Tags: discussion

In [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/15657/how-to-deal-with-discussions-about-finances-with-so-without-it-escalating/15678#15678), the user doesn't back it up with any personal experience or any other information.  I was under the impression that this required a flag from [this meta answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/8151).  I did flag as `Not An Answer` and it was disputed.

Did I use the wrong flag? (Not an answer)  Or am I incorrect in interpreting the back it up policy?

Comment: Nah, you used the right flag, but people in the review queue voted "Looks OK". This is more a problem with reviewers disagreeing with / not knowing about the policy. There's been some confusion: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/how-to-interpret-voting-status-when-a-cm-is-involved

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to proceed if this is the case.  But thank you for at letting me know I was doing the right thing.  I may not personally agree with parts of the "back it up" policy, but I see the reasoning behind it, and I want to try to do the right thing.

Comment: Have you commented under the post suggesting what might be wrong with it and how this could be fixed? As of writing this I don't see any comments indicating that something is wrong with the answer and the OP engaging with the answerer in a way that suggests that they think this answer is valuable.

Comment: I did not, no.  I shall do now.  However, according to the linked meta post, it seemed like it was preferable to quickly get the answer away as it would make other people think those kinds of answers were okay.

Comment: I'll just point out, yet again, that there hasn't been any "official" word about the policy (that I've seen) - everything on the topic so far is basically just a few regular users agreeing over something, with others disagreeing and mods not saying much (at least not much that can be considered an "official" decision). Answers that aren't backed up are also strictly speaking answers, so a "Not an answer" flag can, at best, be considered a hack due to not having flag that's actually applicable, which users who don't follow Meta will probably always decline.

Comment: @NotThatGuy The not an answer flag is generally used for any answer that isn't of sufficient quality for the site, for instance link only answers. We also use the not an answer flag that just says "Do this" without any substantiation of why that is an appropriate course of action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did I use the wrong flag? (Not an answer) Or am I incorrect in
>   interpreting the back it up policy?

No, you did well. The answer is indeed not substantiated enough and the Not-An-Answer flag is the correct one to use in such a case.
As Em C mentioned in a comment, the problem lies in the people reviewing your flag.

> I did not [leave a comment], no. I shall do now. However, according to the linked meta post, it seemed like it was preferable to quickly get the answer away as it would make other people think those kinds of answers were okay.

yes, removing the answer quickly is preferrable, but that does not exclude leaving a comment stating why the answer is being flagged/removed. 
This way,

1. the reviewers know why it was flagged and
2. the author of the answer knows how to edit the answer properly.